# "radial blur" using OpenMP

Tags: c, openmp, pixel, blur, pseudocode

I am trying to find a pseudocode for implementing the "radial blur" using C and OpenMP. "Radial blur" is an operation, in which each pixel is replaced by the average of neighboring pixels. For example for a 3x3 pixel image the centered image's value is given by:

`X4=(X1+X3+X5+X7)/4;`

and the value of any other is given by:

`X0=(X1+X3)2;`

I am searching for a 9x9 implementation with 3 processors. Any kind of help would be amazing. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check the following link?
http://www.drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/faster-image-processing-with-openmp/184405586